# Why is this basic ansible playbook throwing an error?

Tags: yaml, ansible

I am trying to understand how ansible playbooks are structured and I am failing at a basic example:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    # update dependencies
    - name: install apt dependencies
      apt: name={{ item }}
      with_items:
        - python3-arrow
        - python3-netifaces
        - python3-requests
        - python3-docopt
    - name: install pip3 dependencies
      pip: name=scapy-python3 executable=pip3

    # install service
    - name: copy source file
      copy: src=honeysyn.py dst=/opt/sentinel-honeysyn/honeysyn.py
    - name: copy service file
      copy: src=honeysyn.service dst=/etc/systemd/system/honeysyn.service mode=0644
    - name: install service, restart and enable
      systemd:
        name: honeysyn
        daemon_reload: yes
        enabled: yes
        started: yes
```

The error is:

```
The offending line appears to be:

  copy: src=honeysyn.service dst=/etc/systemd/system/honeysyn.service mode=0644
- name: install service, restart and enable
  ^ here
```

I [checked the consistency](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) of the YAML file and the JSON output makes sense:

```
[
  {
    "tasks": [
      {
        "name": "install apt dependencies", 
        "apt": "name={{ item }}", 
        "with_items": [
          "python3-arrow", 
          "python3-netifaces", 
          "python3-requests", 
          "python3-docopt"
        ]
      }, 
      {
        "pip": "name=scapy-python3 executable=pip3", 
        "name": "install pip3 dependencies"
      }, 
      {
        "copy": "src=honeysyn.py dst=/opt/sentinel-honeysyn/honeysyn.py", 
        "name": "copy source file"
      }, 
      {
        "copy": "src=honeysyn.service dst=/etc/systemd/system/honeysyn.service mode=0644", 
        "name": "copy service file"
      }, 
      {
        "systemd": {
          "started": true, 
          "enabled": true, 
          "name": "honeysyn", 
          "daemon_reload": true
        }, 
        "name": "install service, restart and enable"
      }
    ], 
    "hosts": "all"
  }
]
```

I found out that the errors are often very much off the real bug (I had the same case as above, but it was an extra space after a `=` in a completely different place) - thus the whole playbook.

**What is wrong with this playbook?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `systemd` module that you are attempting to use is present in Ansible 2.2 (which is not released as far as I know) and hence will not work with any of the currently available Ansible versions.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/systemd_module.html

Comment: You are correct, thank you. It is amazing how useless these error messages are (I would never have thought of that error when looking at the output).

Answer (score 1):

As @Amit pointed out, it's not released yet.

Ansible seems to have a very zealous documentation release schedule, which sometimes outstrips the release of the actual supporting code :-)

Maybe try [the `service` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/service_module.html) instead for now, something like this should work:

```
- name: install service, enable and start
  service:
    name: honeysyn
    enabled: yes
    state: started
```

Comment: Yes, I used `service`instead, with a `notify` to run `systemctl daemon-reload`instead of the (unsupported) `daemon_reload`